# Python convert byte array to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

i would like help to convert byte to dictionnary, i have;

> received message: b'req:21;num:54771377;INFO:;GATE:N;'

i would like

> d1 = {'req':21,'num':54771377,'INFO':,'GATE':N}

thank you

Comment: hello, what did you done to make this? Can you please show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that with a gencomp piped into a dictionary (drop the empty fields). Split according to semicolon after having converted the bytes to string (assumption: data inside the bytes object is ASCII)

```
s = b"req:21;num:54771377;INFO:;GATE:N;"
d = dict(toks.split(":") for toks in s.decode("ascii").split(";") if toks)

print(d)
```

result:

```
{'INFO': '', 'GATE': 'N', 'req': '21', 'num': '54771377'}
```

notes:

1. a dictcomp would be tempting like this `d = {toks.split(":")[0] : toks.split(":")[1] for toks in s.decode("ascii").split(";") if toks}` but it would mean that you split twice as too many on colon
2. if you have non-ascii data, you can still do the job, but the data will remain as `bytes`: `d = dict(toks.split(b":") for toks in s.split(b";") if toks)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
str = b'req:21;num:54771377;INFO:;GATE:N;'.decode("ascii") 
arr = str.split(';')[::-1]
arr = [x.split(':') for x in arr if x != '']
return dict(arr)
```

Result:

```
{u'INFO': u'', u'GATE': u'N', u'num': u'54771377', u'req': u'21'}
```

Repl: https://repl.it/X3G/8284